# wp-query, pull children of parent page

Tags: wp-query, loop, child-pages

So here's what I'm trying to do: I'm trying to develop a theme that shows any sub-pages on the parent page. I've gotten this running successfully with a WP_query and a simple loop:

```
<!--show sub pages on this page-->
<?php $childargs = array( 'post_parent' => $post->ID, 'post_type' => 'page', 'posts_per_page' => '-1', 'orderby' => 'menu_order', 'order' => 'ASC' );      
$child = new WP_Query($childargs);

// only show the navbar on pages with sub-children
if ($child->have_posts()) { ?>
    <div class="sub">
    <div class="pw">
        <?php if ($child->have_posts()) : while ($child->have_posts()) : $child->the_post(); ?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        <?php endwhile; endif;

        wp_reset_query(); ?>
    </div>
    </div><!--sub-->
<?php } ?>
```

This code displays absolutely nothing on the child pages themselves, which is the correct behavior. I want the child pages show this nav, but I don't know how to do that. $childargs references the postid, which in the case of the child page will be the child page (which has no children of its own).

How can I modify this code so that it not only displays on parent pages, but on child pages as well? A demo page can be found here: http://sheepish-lab637.com/one/about/ with sub-children of its own.

Edit: perhaps this could be better accomplished by a Wordpress menu, which would also have the advantage of bundling the default current_page_item classes and such.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm wondering if I can manipulate WP_query to get the child pages of a child page's parent. . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a child page, the `post_parent` will be a non-zero value, so you could check for that:

```
if( 0 == $post->post_parent ){
    // no parent, get children of this page
    $childargs['post_parent'] = $post->ID;
} else {
    // has parent, get children of parent page
    $childargs['post_parent'] = $post->post_parent;
}
```

This is assuming your child pages are just a single level below the parent pages. Otherwise, you can fetch all the ancestors of a page with [`get_post_ancestors`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_ancestors), and get the ID of the highest level parent:

```
$parents = get_post_ancestors( $post->ID );
$top_level_page = $parents[ count($parents) - 1 ];
```